# Typename and typedef in the creation of an iterator

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, typename

I have this code:

```
template <typename T>
class CircularBuffer
{
 public:
  typename typedef std::list<T>::iterator iterator;

  //other code
};
```

What does the typename in the iterator declaration do?  I know the typedef is saying "I have a list iterator that i want to call 'iterator'.  But what is the purpose of the typename?  Is it just cause my list can store any typename T that I need it? Is it for something else?

Thanks,

Tom

Edit: Is it because the list iterator is a qualified dependent type, and so I need typename before it?  Or, more correctly, the typedef I am defining, 'iterator' which is based on the type std::list::iterator is a qualified dependent type since it is an iterator of a qualified dependent list?

Comment: Shot answer: because the compiler can't figure out if `X<T>::Y` is a static class variable or a type name without expanding the template, so it assumes that it's a static class variable unless you explicitly say that it's a type name with the `typename` keyword.

Comment: It's `typedef typename`, not vice versa. Is that a copy-paste error?

Comment: That is not a copy-paste error, that is from an old test that I am studying - it is actually in the Professor's solution code for the overall problem.  I can't imagine he has it wrong.....

Comment: @traggatmot Imagine it. Definitely wrong, and meaningless.

Comment: @Potatoswatter, so just reversing it makes it correct?  OK.  And then typename is used to indicate that T is a typename, right?

Comment: @traggatmot Yes. Then it indicates that `std::list<T>::iterator` is a typename. It associates with the whole series of items joined by `::` but applies only to the last, namely `iterator`. It would probably be clearer if it were written `std::list<T>::typename iterator`, and the `template` keyword does work that way (see other Q&A), but I think the `typename` rule was specced first so we're stuck with it.